# pip install does not work from dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am getting following error while trying to run pip.

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt'

The command '/bin/sh -c pip3.6 install -r /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My dockerfile looks like this...

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1

RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

RUN yum update

RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git

RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch/
RUN cd /home/elasticsearch/

RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git

WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings

RUN cd /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings

RUN pip3.6 install -r /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt

CMD ["python3.6", "/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/src/main.py"]
```

I have checked that these commands run successfully on the server if run one command at a time from command-prompt.

Comment: Does the file `requirements.txt` exist ? Can you see it in the container files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1

RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

RUN yum update

RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git

RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch/

WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch/

RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git

RUN pip3.6 install -r /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt

CMD ["python3.6", "/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/src/main.py"]
```

The issue with the original Dockerfile is the `RUN cd /path`. Each build stage executes in a separate container thus `cd` 'ing to a directory does nothing. For changing active directory during build use `WORKDIR` instruction.

Comment: The default `WORKDIR` is `/usr/share/elasticsearch` for the `elasticsearch:7.3.1` image, can remove the `WORKDIR` altogether and `clone` / install from there as pointed out by @LinPy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57689883/1423507).

Comment: @masseyb Sure, but it seems the questioner tries to checkout git project in specific directory(based on the cd thing) thus for me `WORKDIR` seems the way to go.

Comment: For sure, `WORKDIR` ftw (I +1'd). Will note that could chain the `mkdir` / `cd` / `clone` operations though (gross but would work, timtodi) i.e. `RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch && cd /home/elasticsearch && git clone ...`.

Answer (score 2):

the file `requirements.txt` is in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/text-embeddings` not `/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings`

this will work:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1

RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

RUN yum update

RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git


RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git

WORKDIR /usr/share/elasticsearch/text-embeddings

RUN pip3.6 install -r /usr/share/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt

CMD ["python3.6", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/src/main.py"]
```

Comment: The `requirements.txt` is in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/text-embeddings` due to the `clone` operation taking place in `/usr/share/elasticsearch` (default `WORKDIR` of the `elasticsearch:7.3.1` image) as the `mkdir` and `cd` instructions don't work as OP has expected as pointed out by @leopal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57689926/1423507).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to a combination of a couple of the answers here @leopal is correct whereas the `mkdir` and `cd` are run in different layers and don't result in what you're expecting ref. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57689926/1423507).

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum update
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git
RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch/
RUN cd /home/elasticsearch/
RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

... running the container (i.e. `docker build -t so:57689606 . && docker run --rm -it so:57689606`) will drop you in a shell in the `/usr/share/elasticsearch` directory with all the files present as pointed out by @LinPy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57689883/1423507). Adding the `WORKDIR` after your checkout is moving you to a directory where the repository wasn't cloned (e.g. `/home/elasticsearch`).

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum update
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git
RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch/
RUN cd /home/elasticsearch/
RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git
WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

... will drop you in a shell inside an empty folder when you run the container (hence the `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` error).

Also, specifying a `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it doesn't already exist, e.g. your `RUN mkdir /home/elasticsearch/` and `RUN cd /home/elasticsearch` instructions don't work as you'd expect and are merely adding useless layers to your final image. Functional `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum update
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip git
WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch/
RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git
RUN python3.6 -m pip install -r /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt
CMD ["python3.6", "/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/src/main.py"]
```

Finally, removing the unnecessary layers in your final image (optimized `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.3.1                                                                           
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum update && \
    yum install -y \
        python36u \
        python36u-libs \
        python36u-devel \
        python36u-pip \
        git && \
    yum clean all
WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch/
RUN git clone https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings.git && \
    python3.6 -m pip install -r /home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.6"]
CMD ["/home/elasticsearch/text-embeddings/src/main.py"]
```

**Note**: the `apt` packages are purposely split on multiple lines, makes it easier to see at a glance what changes in a `git diff` imo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in Dockerfile and try it.

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt